# JQuery.AJAX fails even though firefox says code 200

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I cannot get the jQuery to return a success even though the URL which it generates works. The code is as follows:

```
    var baseURL = "http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0.json";
    var apiKey = "myAPIKEy";

    $.ajax
    ({
        type: "GET",
        url: baseURL,
        data: { apikey: apiKey },
        success:function()
        {
            alert('here');
        },
        complete:function(data)
        {
            return data;
        }
    });
```

It does not hit success (I took out failed but it goes into failed). I am not sure why this is failing given I copy paste the generated URL and it works and spits back a response. Please let me know what other information I can provide. I am sorry for being a bit vague. Any help is greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: problem is simple... it is a cross domain call. The request will complete, but browser security restrictions don't allow use of the data unless it is jsonp or CORS enabled

Comment: Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: Use JSONP if they support it.

Comment: can you get the webdevepoer extension in chrome and put a breakpoint in the failed function and look at the error message that should tell you what exactly is the error.

Comment: Get yourself [easyXDM](http://easyxdm.net/wp/), and fughetaboutit...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will work,  for cross domain

```
var baseURL = "http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0.json";
var apiKey = "myAPIKEy";

$.getJSON (baseURL + "?callback=?", { apikey: apiKey }, function(data){
        return data;
});
```

Comment: assuming the API serves JSONP, you still need to add `dataType`

Comment: by adding `?callback=` jquery will trreat it as crossdomain url and add its call back function. Why down vote ?!?!??!

Comment: Well it's `?callback=?` sorry

Comment: I am getting an "invalid label" error back. Adding ( ) does not solve this issue. Do you have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Found the solution. I needed to change the $.get to JSONP. For some reason this function does not work. Ill put up the answer but I am sure this should work too...

Answer (score 0):

Per Rotten Tomatoes you can use JSONP:

```
http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0.json?apikey=[your_api_key]&callback=mycallbackfn
```

**A simple example:**

$.getJSON (http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0.json, { apikey: apiKey, callback : uniqueCallback });

function uniqueCallback(data)
{
    //Data will be sent to this function
}

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. You have to change it to JSONP for rotten tomatoes. Lesson learned, consult the documentation in the future...

http://developer.rottentomatoes.com/docs/read/json/v10/examples